How to test the TextToSpeech class in Kotlin / Android Studio?
I created a new project in Android Studio and pasted the following code as the main module:
The app gets built, but it crashes instantly when starting.
How does one debug such a code / app with A.S. ?
My Android Studio is:
Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-232.10300.40.2321.11567975, built on March 13, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.4.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.Locale

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private lateinit var tts: TextToSpeech

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Create a Button programmatically
        val button = Button(this).apply {
            text = "Speak"
            setOnClickListener {
                // Initialize the TextToSpeech object if not already initialized
                if (!::tts.isInitialized) {
                    tts = TextToSpeech(context, this@MainActivity)
                }
                Log.d("XXX", "Testing logging")
                // Speak text when the button is clicked
                tts.speak("Hello, world!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
            }
        }

        // Set the Button as the content view
        setContentView(button)
    }


    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            // Set the language for the TextToSpeech engine
            val result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                // Handle error
                Log.d("XXX", " Language problem!")
            } else {
                // Ready to use TextToSpeech
                tts.speak("Hello, world!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("XXX", " onInit() failed!")
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (::tts.isInitialized) {
            tts.stop()
            tts.shutdown()
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}

